# Bootstrap 4 tooltip always positions at the bottom with different placements in table cell

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have this issue within a table cell where the placement always goes to the bottom of the cell.  I want it to show at the top on hover, but it just wont do it.  I believe its th table-responsive class.

```js
var handler = function (e) {

 $(this).addClass('tooltip-init').tooltip({
                            html: true,
                            placement: "top",
                            delay: { "show": 100, "hide": 0 },
                            trigger: 'hover'
                        }).tooltip('show');
                        
                         };
                        
                       $('.tooltip1').on('mouseenter', handler);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th  class="tooltip1" title="test" style="border: solid 1px #FF0000;">ToolTip Enabled
  </th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
<th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  </tr><tr>
<th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  <th>test</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a bit complicated to fix this on the fly. But the bootstrap tooltip will always look for available space in the parent container box and if there is no available in the desired position, it will automatically place it on the opposite side. So one of the possible workarounds to fix this is to add a `padding` to the desired side *(Which is in your case is top of the table)* and create a space in the table box for the tooltip.

So it will be something like this:

```js
var handler = function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('tooltip-init').tooltip({
    html: true,
    placement: "top",
    delay: {
      "show": 100,
      "hide": 0
    },
    trigger: 'hover'
  }).tooltip('show');
};

$('.tooltip1').on('mouseenter', handler);
```

```css
.table-responsive {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="tooltip1" title="test" style="border: solid 1px #FF0000;">ToolTip Enabled
        </th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

### UPDATE

As you mentioned the originally suggested workaround is not ideal, I came up with another solution that is more convenient and reasonable. As I mentioned before the problem is lies beneath the parent wrapper box behaviour, in your particular case you used `table-responsive` class as a wrapper your whole table, bootstrap will manually set its `overflow` to `auto` so whatever element is overflowing the wrapper box will be ignored and in this case, it will be shown in the opposite side, so to fix this, you should only override the `overflow` for this element.

So it would be something like this:

```js
var handler = function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('tooltip-init').tooltip({
    html: true,
    placement: "top",
    delay: {
      "show": 100,
      "hide": 0
    },
    trigger: 'hover'
  }).tooltip('show');
};

$('.tooltip1').on('mouseenter', handler);
```

```css
div.table-responsive {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="tooltip1" title="test" style="border: solid 1px #FF0000;">ToolTip Enabled
        </th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
        <th>test</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess thats an option but not ideal. Why would it treat the responsive class as a container though?

Comment: @MikeFlynn Yea, it was just a possible workaround and it won't look nice . I'm not sure what do you mean by *responsive class*, but as I said earlier this is all about main wrapper box behaviour. So I just update the answer for more information.

Comment: What makes a wrapper the main and what css needs to be applied. I have many wrappers on other items and tooltip works fine. If I remove the table-responsive class it works fine also.

Comment: @MikeFlynn The most outer parent will be the main one, so in this particular case the `table-responsive` will be the main one *(main box)* for the table, and as you said it won't happen everywhere, it will happen whenever the overflow of the main parent is `auto` or `hidden`, so to override it, you need to assign an id *(Or whatever with high specificity priority)* to that wrapper, then make its overflow visible with `overflow: visible;`.

Comment: @MikeFlynn Did you come up with a conclusion?

Comment: I havent tried anything yet.  If I want a responsive table then I dont want overflow visible.

Answer (score 0):

add css style `padding-top: 50px;` to .table-responsive.

test: https://jsfiddle.net/a0jht7v2/